# weather degrees xml parsing

Tags: android

I just tried the sampl code of getting the weather fom google weather xml but the code gives IOException  but i dont know the reason i just did same as videos:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1rtldBTzCE
here is my code:

```
public class MyProjectActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListene  {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView tv;
    EditText edt1,edt2;
    Button btn;
    String site="hhttp://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Lincoln,Nebraska";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV);
    edt1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    edt2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
    btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

    btn.

setOnClickListener( this);


    }

public void onClick(View V){

        String c=edt1.getText().toString();
        String s=edt2.getText().toString();
        StringBuilder url=new StringBuilder();
        url.append(c+","+s);
        String fullUrl=url.toString();
        try{
            URL website=new URL(fullUrl);
            SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp=spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr=sp.getXMLReader();
            handler work=new handler();
            xr.setContentHandler(work);
            xr.parse(new InputSource (website.openStream()));
            String information=work.getInfo();
            tv.setText(information);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            tv.setText("error");
        }



    }



package com.myProject.pro;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class handler extends DefaultHandler {

    geterSetter info=new geterSetter();

    public String getInfo(){
        return info.dataToString();
    }
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(localName.equals("city")){
        String city=attributes.getValue("data");
        info.setCity(city);
        }else if(localName.equals("temp_c")){
            String t=attributes.getValue("data");
            int temp=Integer.parseInt(t);
            info.setTemp(temp);
            }

    }


}
```

//set get Class
package com.myProject.pro;

```
public class geterSetter {
    int temp;
    String city;

    public void setCity(String c){
        city=c;
    }
    public void setTemp(int t){
        temp=t;
    }
   public String dataToString(){
       return city+temp;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are having troubles with the fact your url schema has 2 Hs: `hhttp` not `http`: `hhttp://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Lincoln,Nebraska`. Remove one `h`.

Comment: @user1404380 can you add the stack trace of the exception, please?

Comment: how can i do this?? sry but i'm new in android^_^!

Comment: @user1404380 you mean add the stack trace?